# Do I have to pay Zakat even if I pay income tax as an employee?

Tags: quran, zakat

Salam folks,

Do I have to give a Zakat during Ramadan? If am paying a good amount of income tax every month.

One more thing : I only fasted a single day due to diabetes. Feeling guilty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walaikum Salam. Yes. You will need to pay zakat. Income tax is paid to the government. Zakat is to be paid to muslims. See [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/46209/categories-on-which-zakaah-may-be-spent) for detailed list of categories.

Answer to your next question is, you need to either make up for the missed days if you have ability to fast at later stage or pay your Fidyah (Expiation) if it is terminal illness, or inability to fast because of old age.

Another common misconception amongst muslims is that zakat is to be paid in Ramadan. Your Zakat year should begin on the date your wealth equals or surpasses the Nisab, that will initiate a new year for Zakat. You will then see a year after this new date whether your wealth equals to or surpasses the Nisab. This is referred to as your ‘**Zakat due date’**. Zakat is due immediately upon your '**Zakat due date**'. If you’re not sure when this is or you’re paying for the first time, simply work out the day you first owned wealth over and above the Nisab threshold (if you don’t know the exact date you can estimate). Muslims pay in the month of Ramadan because the reward is multiplied.

Comment: Shukriyaa.Should I donate to my living geographical location or I can donate wherever I want? –

Comment: I disagreed with you. Income tax surely goes to Government but then government utilizes it for the welfare of the country which means including Muslim citizens.

Comment: @tester you can donate wherever you want.

Comment: @tester Do you disagree because 1) It doesn't suit your desire 2) or because you have a evidence from Quran and Sunnah which can establish the validity of income tax as zakat? Islam is based on evidences not based on our whims and desires.

Comment: Ok, got it.No desire or anything such that. Moreover, it's common sense.

Answer (score 0):

Wasak

Income tax doesn't negate your duty to pay Zakat if the savings has crossed the [nisaab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nisab#Ni%E1%B9%A3%C4%81b_of_Currency)  threshold.

With respect to your inability to keep fasts due to a medical reason, please look into the concept of [Fidya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidyah_and_Kaffara#Fidyah) in Islam.

Comment: Should I donate to my living geographical location or I can donate wherever I want?

Comment: The sunnah is to do it locally but there is no prohibition on how to distribute the Zakat as long as the recipients are eligible. Also relatives & neighbors (if eligible) have preference over others.